# Is it possible create a new dict (dictionary) in a python class?

Tags: python, class, csv

Hi I writing a code based on my Assignment and I am on  Classes I have done most of the code but want to ask a question can I create a empty dict in a class:

Is the new dict(dictionary) in class is in this format

```
dict = {}
```

or

```
self.dict = {}
```

Comment: Yes you can do that, but in the first case don't use `dict` as a variable name since it's the name of the built-in type. You can also use `variable = dict()`, but simply `variable = {}` is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Almost anything (if not everything) that can be stored in a regular variable can be stored in a class property. You could've easily tested this in Python interactive shell. Also, listen to the comment above and never name a variable `dict`.

Example:

```
>>> class hold_dict:
...     pass
... 
>>> d = hold_dict()
>>> d.d = {"key":"item"}
>>> d.d
{'key': 'item'}
```

Uh... I want to write more but I think that's it.